# Yaml parsing issue on redhat

Tags: ruby, yaml

On RHEL5 box for a rails app running on ruby 1.9.2, the following yaml is parsed in a way that the login_type is set to "ldap" even in staging environment. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
defaults: &defaults
  login_type: ldap

staging:
  <<: *defaults
  login_type: developer
```

Comment: How do you access these variables? Did you create a staging.rb environment file?

Comment: Yes i have a staging.rb file. I am not having this issue on Ubuntu and Mac OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have to do with [this Bundler/Ruby/Psych issue](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1038) -- it's already been fixed, but not in the current release of Ruby.

The reason you don't see the issue with OS X (and probably Ubuntu) is that unless you manually installed libyaml before compiling/installing Ruby, Psych does not get installed; it falls back to Syck, which works fine. (Try doing a `require 'psych'` on OS X and it will fail, whereas it will work fine in RHEL5)

For now, you can either force the YAML parser to use Syck instead of Psych by putting this at the end of your `boot.rb` (but beware -- a future version of Ruby will no longer include Syck):

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

Or preferably, you should just use a non-DRY YAML file (without the defaults) for the time being.

**UPDATE**

The newest release of Ruby that came out today (1.9.2-p290) includes a fix for this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot dmarkow. Adding the line at the end of boot.rb did work!